# jquery ui: sortable vs Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am maintaining a website built with jquery ui 1.8.18.
there I've seen the following code...

```
$('div.sortables').Sortable({
    accept     : 'content',
    tolerance  : 'intersect',
    opacity    : 0.8,
    fit        : false,
    distance   : 25
});
```

the `distance` property has no effect here...
while in the jquery ui docs,
they said if `distance` is specified,
then sort works only after mouse moved `distance` px...

if I changed `Sortable()` to `sortable()` then `distance` property works but the design got crippled...

how to set the distance property to work with `Sortable()`?

Comment: `Sortable()` with uppercase `S` is not jQuery UI, it's some other widget.

Comment: `accept` and `fit` are not part of jQuery-UI Sortable.

Comment: So the problem seems to be that you're mixing up two different widgets.

Comment: I got it...
it was a different plugin...
but as all files are minified to 1, I thought it was jquery ui...

Comment: thanks for your assist [Barmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI requires lowercase when initializing an interaction. Sortable interaction should be initialized as ".sortable();" rather than ".Sortable();"

Some of the options you are using are not used in jQuery ui "sortable", however they do have similar options. For example, `accept` can be changed to `items`.

For more information about sortable functionality and options, check out the documentation: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/